Showing that, for $f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, if $0<\|(x,y)\|<\delta$, then $\|f(x,y)\|<\delta^2/2$
From Susan Jane Colley's Vector Calculus page 138.

For
$$
f(x,y) = xy \left(\frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}\right)
$$
Show that if $0 < \| (x,y) \| < \delta $, then $\|f(x,y)\| < \delta^2/2$

From part a) we showed that for any real $a, b$, then $2|ab| \leq a^2 + b^2$.
My proof:
First we prove that $x^2 - y^2 < \delta^2$. If
$$
0 < || (x,y) || < \delta \\\\
0 < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta\\\\
0 < x^2 + y^2 < \delta^2
$$
and since $x^2 - y^2  \leq x^2 + y^2$ then $x^2 - y^2 < \delta^2$.
Now to look back at $f(x,y)$:
$$
| f(x,y) | = \left\| xy \Bigg(\frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \Bigg) \right\| \\\\
= |xy| \Bigg(\frac{|x^2 - y^2|}{x^2 + y^2} \Bigg)\\\\
\leq |xy| \Bigg(|\frac{|x^2 - y^2|}{2|xy|} \Bigg)\\\\
= \frac{|x^2 - y^2|}{2}\\\\
\leq \frac{\delta^2}{2}
$$
My question is whether my reasoning in the first section that $x^2 - y^2  \leq x^2 + y^2$ then $x^2 - y^2 < \delta^2$ is valid? Would sincerely appreciate the help.

Looks ok. It is valid.

I think what you really want to show is not $x^2 - y^2 \leq x^2 + y^2$, but $|x^2-y^2| \leq x^2+y^2$. But that's not too much harder.

You could usefully explain the (correct) step that relies on the inequality $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2|xy||$.

Thank you. I will redo this to prove this point more rigorously.

Your proof is correct, but can be shortened, applying the same reasoning. For $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ we have
$$|xy|\,{|x^2-y^2|\over  x^2+y^2}\le {x^2+y^2\over 2}\,{x^2+y^2\over x^2+y^2}={x^2+y^2\over 2}\le {\delta^2\over 2}$$

Thank you very much! This is very neat though I think the final $\delta^2$ term should be $\frac{\delta^2}{2}$ if you agree?

Thanks for accepting. Corrected.
